# Why Minium Developer is not reading JSON files?

Tags: json, cucumber

As we know, Minium Developer supports JSON files and it shows the code in green colour but, yesterday it turned into white colour code like plain text and doesn't recognize anything, even if I import an existing proyect or create a new proyect. Why is this happening?

**The screenshot**

[image: Minium Developer]

**The JSON code**

```
{
  "loginJSON":
  {
      "url": "https://minium.vilt.io/docs/developer/minium-developer/",
            "idioma": "Castellano",
            "usuario": "user",
            "pin1": "2236",
            "pin2": "6322"
  },
    "altaHuchaJSON":
    {
        "motivo": "Viaje",
        "nombre": "Crear guardiola test",
        "objetivo": "300",
        "fecha": "15/8/2019",
        "aportacion": "100"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Json files are always presented as white text, since Minium Developer does not support the syntax highlight for the json files, but Minium Developer is able to detect and read json files.